# Eclipse SDK Manager won't show

Tags: android, eclipse

My SDK manager won't open. I already tried everything I could find on the Internet including reinstalling Java, reinstalling the entire ADT and altering the android.bat file in sdk/tools.

When I try to start the SDK in Eclipse, I just get a notification saying:

**C:\Users\Dejan is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. The system cannot find the path specified.**

Comment: Is our JDK and eclipse up to date?

Comment: Have you tried to run it from the command line?

Comment: yes I updated everything 20 minutes ago. But I haven't tried to run it from the command line. How does it work?

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out! If you feel like learning it anyways, [click here](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) to see how to build and run from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can launch the SDK Manager in one of the following ways:

- From Eclipse (with ADT), select Window > Android SDK Manager.
- From Android Studio, select Tools > Android > SDK Manager.
- On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android SDK   directory.
- On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the Android SDK, then execute android sdk.

In Eclipse: Window - Preferences - Android - SDK Location and setup SDK path which is by default in Windows: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\`

Comment: It worked somehow by dragging the entire adt bunduru into Program Files (x86)\Android.  Thanks for your quick response :)